# Jqgrid data not saved on edited row when select all clicked

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I Use Jqgrid like this:

```
 $("#grdMain" + TabID).jqGrid({

        datatype: 'local',

        colNames: ['ID', 'LookupCode','LookupTitle'],
        colModel: [

                    { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', hidden: true, editable: true, dataType: "number" },
                    { name: 'LookupCode', index: 'LookupCode', hidden: true },
                    { name: 'LookupTitle', index: 'LookupTitle', width: 100 }],
        localReader: {
            repeatitems: false,

            cell: "",
            id: "ID"
        },

        scrollOffset: 20,
        rowNum: 20,
        rowList: [10, 20],
        sortorder: 'asc',
        viewrecords: true,
        autowidth: false,
        gridview: true,
        forceFit: false,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        multiselect: true,
        width: 1255,
        height: 340,
        editurl: 'clientArray',
        rowNum: 1000000,
        direction: 'rtl',
        caption: '',
        gridstate: 'hidden',
        rownumbers: true,
        loadError: ServiceFailed,
        onSelectRow: function (rowid, isSelected) {

            $(this).editRow(rowid, true);

            $("#" + rowid + "_LookupTitle", "#grdMain" + TabID).lookup();

        },
        beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {

            return DetailGridUtility.SaveDetail($(this), rowid, LastID);
        }, onSelectAll: function (ids, status) {

        }

    });
```

Suppose there are 10 rows on grid and I selected 2 first rows and second row is on edit mode and I changed lookupTitle ( and row still on edit mode), Now I click On SelectAll CheckBox,after that changes to the second row that are in edit mode are not considered

How can I fix this Error ?

Is there a method befor selectAll? ( If there is, I can save Changes Befor SellectAll)

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used - Guriddo jqGrid, free-jqGrid or jqGrid <= 4.7? Is LookupTitle editabe, since it is not editable - how you edit it?

Comment: I use  version 4.4.1

Comment: What about second question about editable field? What do a function lookup when you select a row? Please answer all questions if you want to get help

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I found selectAll checkbox Tag and wrote function for mousedown event and saved grid on this method. This event call befor check mark all rows. I 's not possible to use  Click event or change event because these events call after check mark all rows

```
$("#cb_grdMain" + TabID).mousedown(function () {

   //Save Grid 
    });
```